# Can same verilog or vhdl code work on different fpga board

Tags: fpga

I am new to fpga and i need to understand one thing.

In mcu, the code must be specific to hardware i cannot use raspberry pi code on arduino. However since the fpga chip looks at the verilog or vhdl code and creates the circuit we have designed, Can the same vhdl or verilog code be used on different fpga boards(by only editing the clockspeed or pin names accordingly) if there is enough gate source?

I have basys2 board and there are more tutorials on different boards if same code and logic would work then i will not buy another board and learn on basys2 by using different board sources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes both of them will work well. If it is plain code(without any library as in VHDL) it will work.